how to resolve WebSocket connection issue error code 1006 On GCP?
I am facing web socket disconnection problem with 1006 on production environment. I unable to find the exact problem. We tested without firewall restriction on GCP , that also not working as expected. Could you please someone help me to resolve the problem.
Tech: Spring boot 3.x & Java 17.
error from GCP logs


We need more context. Where is hosted your app? do you have network layer? GCP (like Load Balancer) and 3rd party (Like CloudFlare)

This application is hosted in GCP environment. We used load balancer on server instance,...Please tell me the required information , I will share you.....
